# Enlarge text three times and back to initial size

Tags: jquery, css

I have link and div element. After click to the link I want to enlarge text inside the div. It's possible enlarge text three times and for the fourth time size has to back to the initial size

```js
$('.bigger').click(function () {
  ('#outer-wrap').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css("font-size", "115%")
  });
})
```

```html
<a class="bigger" href="#">Some text</a>


<div id="outer-wrap">paragraph</div>
```

Now I have something like that. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you don't need to add an on click event handler to outer-wrap.  Instead keep an array of the sizes you want and a variable for the current number of clicks and change the size according to how many times the link was clicked.

```js
var sizes = ["100%","115%","130%","145%"];
var count = 1;

$('.bigger').click(function () {
  $('#outer-wrap').css("font-size", sizes[count]);
  count = (count+1) % 4;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="bigger" href="#">Some text</a>


<div id="outer-wrap">paragraph</div>
```

Comment: Depending on whether those zoom values are desired or not, you could use your count as a co-efficient instead of having to keep a list. D'oh, i always forget the modulo operator, that's a good choice

Comment: @BenPhilipp Yeah it depends whether Marcin needs a linear increase in the size of the text or not.  If it's not linear I think this is better cause you can put whatever you want for each step.  If it's linear then co-efficient might be better.

Comment: @spaniol6 Yes. Or you could increment like this: http://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/4hor9p6b/3/ , as a 2nd order increment

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var i=0;
$('.bigger').click(function () {
  i=(i+1) %4;
  $('#outer-wrap').css("font-size", (100+15*i)+"%");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/4hor9p6b/

This cycles through i from 0 to 3, and uses that number to increment the zoom level (100%, 115%, 130%, 145%).

This makes it quite elegant and also a bit more dynamic (you can change the 4 behind the modulo without having to change anything else to change the number of steps, and the 15 in the increment to change how much the font is being enlarged by on every click.)

Comment: Using the count to calculate the size at each step is more elegant depending on the use case. +1

Comment: Thanks! In my case I prefere array of sizes